# CanDeactivate guard is not working on child path with wildcard

Tags: angular, router, guard

I have this route in my router configuration (with other routes withouh children)

```
{ 
    path: 'editor', 
    component: EditorWrapComponent, 
    canDeactivate: [
        ConfirmDeactivateGuard,
    ],
    children: [
        {
            path: '**',
            component: EditorComponent,
            canDeactivate: [
                 ConfirmDeactivateGuard,
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

I have it like this because of dynamic children paths.

Guard is working ok when navigating between other main routes. But when i navigate between children routes */editor/something* and */editor/something1* guard is not firing. 
I have also tried canActivetaChild with no success.